# editing remote files locally and committing them to intellijea IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, gitlab, commit, git-commit

[image]

I am currently writing a program with intellijea IDEA. I cloned my gitlab project. However, when I try to create new class, I don't get to see the option to create new class. Please what I am doing wrong? Or is there a better way to resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the content type of a directory. This way IntelliJ can provide context aware menu options for you.

First create a directory. E.g. src/main/java (like maven).

You can set this in the module settings:

[image: Module settings]

Tip: If you use maven or another build tool, you can add support for that tool to your project too.